# Ansible forcing loop over identical items

Tags: ansible

Say I have a vars file with the variables:

```
images:
  - d2ac6a57-3669-44aa-a9f3-9690647ad1c5
  - d2ac6a57-3669-44aa-a9f3-9690647ad1c5
ssh_users:
  - cirros
  - cirros
flavors:
  - 1
  - 2
```

And I have a playbook that loops through these variables and appends them to a file:

```
  - name: Append conf with images
    lineinfile:
      path: ./cloud/etc/conf
      line: "image = {{ item }}"
    loop: "{{ images }}"
#... 
#omitted
```

Ansible will skip over the second items for images and ssh_users because they are identical to the first. How can I force it to print out every item?

Expected output at end of file `./cloud/etc/conf`:

```
image = d2ac6a57-3669-44aa-a9f3-9690647ad1c5
image = d2ac6a57-3669-44aa-a9f3-9690647ad1c5
flavor = 1
flavor = 2
ssh_user = cirros
ssh_user = cirros
```

Actual output:

```
image = d2ac6a57-3669-44aa-a9f3-9690647ad1c5
flavor = 1
flavor = 2
ssh_user = cirros
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out a workaround:

```
  - name: Append conf with config
    blockinfile: 
      path: ./cloud/etc/conf
      block: |
        image = {{ item.0 }}
        ssh_user = {{ item.1 }}
        flavor = {{ item.2 }}
      marker: "# {mark} ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK {{idx+1}}"
    loop: "{{ images | zip(ssh_users, flavors) | list }}"
    loop_control:
      index_var: idx
```

but this only works because each group of items is different - i.e. the flavor is different in this case. If I had all identical items, this wouldn't work .